# Compare 2 strings in C and print equal part

Tags: c, string

How can I compare 2 strings with maximum length 100 and print the equal part of them, like:

```
STRING 1 : ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
STRING 2 : QWERABCDZXVBERTY
```

The equal parts of these strings are : `ABCD`

Comment: what have you tried so far? at least as a beginner you must know how to compare two chars

Comment: What have you considered as an algorithm?  How would you process it if the strings were `XYZABCDEFG` and `QWERABCDZXVBERTYHANDFEDHAMSTER`?  (In your sample, the string lengths are equal; in this, they're of very different lengths.). Which functions from the `<string.h>` header could be useful?  What should you do if there are only single characters that match?

Comment: Look into the [Longest Common Substring problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem). It has psuedocode you should be able to translate directly into C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look if this program can help you. It takes the two strings as arguments from the command line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int *substring(char *s, char *t) {
    int strlen1 = strlen(s);
    int strlen2 = strlen(t);
    int len = strlen1 < strlen2 ? strlen1 : strlen2;
    int i, j, k;
    int longest = 0;
    int **ptr = (int **) malloc(2 * sizeof(int *));
    static int *ret;
    ret = (int *) calloc(strlen1 + 1, sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        ptr[i] = (int *) calloc(strlen2, sizeof(int));

    k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen1; i++) {
        memcpy(ptr[0], ptr[1], strlen2 * sizeof(int));
        for (j = 0; j < strlen2; j++) {
            if (s[i] == t[j]) {
                if (i == 0 || j == 0) {
                    ptr[1][j] = 1;
                } else {
                    ptr[1][j] = ptr[0][j - 1] + 1;
                }
                if (ptr[1][j] > longest) {
                    longest = ptr[1][j];
                    k = 0;
                    ret[k++] = longest;
                }
                if (ptr[1][j] == longest) {
                    ret[k++] = i;
                    ret[k] = -1;
                }
            } else {
                ptr[1][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        free(ptr[i]);
    free(ptr);
    ret[0] = longest;
    return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i, longest, *ret;

    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("usage: longest-common-substring string1 string2\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    ret = substring(argv[1], argv[2]);
    if ((longest = ret[0]) == 0) {
        printf("There is no common substring\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    i = 0;
    while (ret[++i] != -1) {
        printf("%.*s\n", longest, &argv[1][ret[i] - longest + 1]);
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

Test

```
./a.out ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP QWERABCDZXVBERTY
ABCD
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare two strings is a common skill which is very easy to find information. First you should read `string.h` library where you can find a lot of useful function in order to work with strings.
Then the first stupid algorithm is to compare each char of first string with the second and if it matches you add that char to the result. 
But it would be smarter to order the two strings and then compare them, saving many comparisons.